# View field with link to excecute action plugin

Tags: views, 8, actions

How can one add a field in views with a link to a custom Action plugin?

With bulk operations it's possible to create a checkbox to perform an action to a set of results. My actions have an access check that may be different per result so using the checkbox would result in a lot of warnings when the user tries to perform the action and doesn't have access.

I'd prefer to show the action as a link and only show the link when the user has access.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about setting up a route with a csrf token and an access check on a controller that manually performs the action:

```
my_module.my_action_callback:
  path: '/node/{node}/my_action_callback'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ActionController::my_action'
    _title: 'My action'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'perform my action'
    _csrf_token: 'TRUE'
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ActionController::my_action_access'
```

In ActionController::my_action I could perform the action programmatically:

```
\Drupal\system\Entity\Action::load('foo')->execute($data);
```

I had hoped there was a less complex and more elegant way using an existing view plugin.